# How to fill down functions in four columns to where the data in column A stops?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill down functions in four columns to where the data in column A stops, but by the time it gets to the fourth FillDown, it takes a very long time.

Is there any way to rewrite it more efficiently?

```vb
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).End(xlDown)).FillDown

Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],7,2)"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).End(xlDown)).FillDown

Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-22]<>""SO"",RC[-22],RC[-12])"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).End(xlDown)).FillDown

Range("AA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(OR((RC[-22]=""17""),(RC[-22]<>""11""),(RC[-23]=""SO"")),""HQ"",""Remote"")"
Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).End(xlDown)).FillDown
```

Comment: You can write a formula to a range in one go, without filling down. Also see [How to avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: [Entering formula in one go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621448/formula-autofill-down-multiple-columns-using-specific-cells-in-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues here

1. You say *... to where the data in column A stops* but are using `.End(xlDown)` on columns D, E, Z, AA.  This may be filling the formula down to the botton of the sheet.
2. You don't need to `Fill Down`, simply apply the formula to a specified range
3. `Select` is not a needed

Consider this

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or specify the required sheet
    
    With ws
        ' find where data in column A stops
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If LastRow = 1 Then
            ' there is no data in column A
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(LastRow, 4)).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 5), .Cells(LastRow, 5)).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],7,2)"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(LastRow, 26)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-22]<>""SO"",RC[-22],RC[-12])"
        .Range(.Cells(2, 27), .Cells(LastRow, 27)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(OR((RC[-22]=""17""),(RC[-22]<>""11""),(RC[-23]=""SO"")),""HQ"",""Remote"")"
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen pointed out, you can avoid using `.FillDown` by just referencing the full range from the start. You can also avoid `.Select` at the same time by using functions like `.Resize` to reference larger ranges based on the current range.

Additionally, since your macro is writing formulas into cells, you can speed up the code by disabling the auto-calculation that happens whenever a cell is edited. It's also a good idea to disable any events that might be running from the `Worksheet_Change` procedure.

You can disable those two things using `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.EnableEvents = False`. After the code, you will want to return those two settings back to default with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Here's an example of how to implement these suggestions:

```vb
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Range("D2")
        .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],2)"
    End With
    
    With Range("E2")
    .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],7,2)"
    End With
    
    With Range("Z2")
    .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-22]<>""SO"",RC[-22],RC[-12])"
    End With
    
    With Range("AA2")
    .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR((RC[-22]=""17""),(RC[-22]<>""11""),(RC[-23]=""SO"")),""HQ"",""Remote"")"
    End With
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I preserved the `.End(xlDown)` method since I don't know what your sheet looks and that may be the best method to match your data format.